Downgraded package reference on build
I have an analyzer (targeting netstandard2.0) relying on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis v 4.12.0, which in turn has reference to System.Memory v 4.6.0. And I have no direct reference to any other version of System.Memory. Still, the library is built with reference to v 4.0.2.0

Does not make any difference if I add package reference directly to the project.
The generated nuspec file also references only 4.6.0:

deps.json has also no other version in it:

But because of this, the analyzer throws FileNotFoundException on load.
What can I do?
[Update: 2024.12.16]
It seems that it some kind of a redirect, that is solved in general cases, but not when the analyzer is running. Although the version referenced in the library is 4.0.2, but ILSpy actually loads this version, which is also 4.6 at the end of the day:

Even weirder is that the version it is looking for is present and also cached:

I am still getting the error:

19>CSC : warning AD0001: Analyzer 'ApplicableOnConstraintAnalyzer'
threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' with
message 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory,
Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'.

